# How to distribute ERC-20 Token to 7500 address at once?

Tags: solidity

I am working on a solidity contract and on each ethereum received in contract, I want to distribute ERC20 token propotional to ether spent in that transaction to 7500 addresses at once.

To do there could be these 2 ways as given below:

1. To transfer them token at the same time.
2. To save that amount so they can claim later. (push/withdraw method)

But in both the ways I will run out of gas.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you add more context to the question? When do you wanna transfer the ERC20 tokens? When, you receive ether from them in your smart contract?

Comment: suppose their is a function which accepts ether and distribute ERC20 token

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to play with the balanceOf for specific addresses. Essentially the set of addresses you specify would have a starting balance of 0 + x. I think setting the addresses in a single mapping would be considerably cheaper. You might get tot higher amount of "distributions" through this method.

Comment: do you mean using ```mapping(address => uint256) beneficiary;```  in a loop ,to update there reward token to be claimed!